# C - Double Pointer getting lost through function call

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, cstring

Quick C question here. We've been playing with double, triple, even quadruple pointers recently. We though we had a grasp on things until we ran into this problem...

```
char ***data;
data_generator(&data);
char **temp = data[0];          
printf("printing temp[%d]: %s\n",0, temp[0]);
printf("printing temp[%d]: %s\n",1, temp[1]);
dosomething(temp);

int dosomething(char **array) { 

    printf("printing array[%d]: %s\n",0, array[0]);
    printf("printing array[%d]: %s\n",1, array[1]);
    ......
}

int data_generator(char ****char_data) {
    char *command1[2];
    char *command2[2];

    command1[0] = "right";
    command1[1] = "left";

    command2[0] = "up";
    command2[1] = "down";

    char **commandArray[2];

    commandArray[0] = command1;
    commandArray[1] = command2;

    number_of_commands = 2;

    if(number_of_commands > 1){
    *char_data = commandArray;
    }

    return number_of_commands - 1;
}
```

And this prints out...

```
printing temp[0]: right
printing temp[1]: left
Segmentation fault
```

Looks like I have some misconceptions about what happens to a pointer while passed through a function. Any thoughts?

Comment: uh, the size of `char ***data` is 4 bytes (on a 32bit machine), your code assumes that it's somehow much larger...

Comment: I don't see any allocation...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
*char_data = commandArray;
```

You are putting the address of a stack (automatic) array in an outside memory location.  This is a recipe for disaster (undefined behavior), since `commandArray`'s lifetime ends as soon as `data_generator` returns.  The same is true for the elements of `commandArray`, which are themselves pointers to stack array elements.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. To make sure I'm clear here, since all of the elements in commandArray are declared in the scope of data_generator, the system can deallocate those objects as soon as data_generator returns. Is that correct? I'm use to objective-c where "retain" is the solution here. What's the C equivalent?

Comment: It can (and does, though you may not get bitten right away) deallocate all the automatic variables.  This includes the arrays `command1`, `command2`, and `commandArray`.  The general solutions are using memory provided by the caller, or `malloc`.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
char *command1[2];
char *command2[2];
```

to:

```
static char *command1[2];
static char *command2[2];
```

That will keep command1[] and command2[] in retained memory.

That, or malloc() them, as the other poster recommends, though proper use of malloc'c memory requires more considerations than I will discuss here.

Comment: You should mention that for many realistic examples (when more than constants are involved), this will make it non-reentrant.